# Select Common Record with different column from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following 3 tables with duplicate id.I want to retrieve record with same id but having different name and date from all the 3 tables.I need query to get Expected result output.

```
CREATE TABLE Student1
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;
    INSERT INTO Student1
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1,0,4500, 'ram', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,2000, 'shyam', '05/09/2013'),

    (4,0,1500, 'ghanshyam', '08/11/2014')
;


CREATE TABLE Student2
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Student2
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES

    (3,0,4500, 'gopal', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,8000, 'radheshyam', '15/11/2013'),
    (4,1,1500, 'ghanshyam', '18/10/2015')
;

CREATE TABLE Student3
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Student3
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES

    (1,1,4500, 'ram', '14/02/2012'),
    (2,0,6500, 'radhe', '11/11/2014'),
    (3,1,4500, 'gopal', '14/02/2015')
;
```

Excepted Result :

```
   id status    amount     Name        date
   2    0       2000      shyam      05/09/2013
   2    0       6500      radhe      11/11/2014
   2    0       8000    radheshyam   15/11/2013
```

Comment: It is usually a bad design to have three tables with the same columns.  You should put them in the same table, with a column specifying "1", "2", or "3".

Answer (score 1):

You just use `union all` to bring the tables together.  One way is:

```
select s.*
from (select s.* from student1 s union all
      select s.* from student2 s union all
      select s.* from student3 s
     ) s
where id = 2;
```

As I say in the comment, though, normally you would have three tables rather than one.

I realize that I might have misunderstood the question.  If you want to *find* records that have the same id but different names, then use:

```
select s.id, group_concat(s.name) as names
from (select s.* from student1 s union all
      select s.* from student2 s union all
      select s.* from student3 s
     ) s
group by s.id
having count(distinct name) = 3 -- or perhaps >= 2, depending on what you mean
```

If you want the full records, you can join this back to the original tables.

EDIT:

If you want all the original rows:

```
select s.*
from (select s.id, group_concat(s.name) as names
      from (select s.* from student1 s union all
            select s.* from student2 s union all
            select s.* from student3 s
           ) s
      group by s.id
      having count(distinct name) = 3 
     ) ss join
     (select s.* from student1 s union all
      select s.* from student2 s union all
      select s.* from student3 s
     ) s
     on ss.id = s.id;
```

Comment: I want to retrieve full records so how will be the query please

Comment: I just need the complete record with same id but different name and different date .